# Object with nested arrays of Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have an object with nested arrays of promises.

```
 let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'url'));
 let object = {
  registration: [promise, promise, promise],
   contract: [promise, promise, promise],
   businessLicense: [promise, promise, promise],
   businessPlan: [promise, promise, promise]
 };
```

I need a function that would give the following result using `Promise.all`

```
   resolvePromisesFunction(object).then(result => console.log(result))

   // the output should be
   {
     registration: [ 'url', 'url', 'url' ],
     contract: [ 'url', 'url', 'url' ],
     businessLicense: [ 'url', 'url', 'url' ],
     businessPlan: [ 'url', 'url', 'url' ]
   }
```

Thx!

Comment: Provide a more real world use case. Not really clear what you are looking for

Comment: React/Node app with direct files uploads to S3. Browser will upload files to S3 directly and send an object with resolved promises/urls to the node backend.

Comment: That is still vague with regard to how the arrays shown get constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chaining promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining) along with Promise.all:

```js
let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'url'));
var obj = {
   registration: [promise, promise, promise],
   contract: [promise, promise, promise],
   businessLicense: [promise, promise, promise],
   businessPlan: [promise, promise, promise]
 };
 
function resolvePromisesFunction(obj) {
 let resolvedObj = {};
 return Promise.all(Object.keys(obj).map(service => {
   return Promise.all(obj[service])
      .then(result => resolvedObj[service] = result);
 })).then(result => resolvedObj);
  
}

resolvePromisesFunction(obj).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: What is this weird output? `/**ref:3**/`

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over your known promises, `Promise.all`ing them, and then `Promise.all` that result.

```js
let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'url'));
let object = {
  registration: [promise, promise, promise],
  contract: [promise, promise, promise],
  businessLicense: [promise, promise, promise],
  businessPlan: [promise, promise, promise]
};

const promises = [];
Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  promises.push(Promise.all(object[key]));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
  const returnedObject = {};
  result.forEach((value, index) => {
    returnedObject[Object.keys(object)[index]] = value;
  });
  console.log(returnedObject);
});
```

Comment: Fixed. Although there is probably an even cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that resolve deep nested object recursive. looking for all promise no mather how deep your object or array is

```js
// Resolves array
const promiseMap = (promiseList, functor) => 
  Promise.all(promiseList.map(promiseOrValue =>
    Promise.resolve(promiseOrValue).then(functor)
  ))

// Resolves objects
const promiseProps = obj =>
  Promise.all(Object.keys(obj).map(key =>
    Promise.resolve(obj[key]).then(val => {
      obj[key] = val;
    })
  )).then(() => obj)

// Resolves recrusive deep objects
const resolveNestedPromises = obj =>
  Promise.resolve(obj).then(obj => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return promiseMap(obj, obj => resolveNestedPromises(obj));
    }
    else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object'  && obj.constructor === Object) {
      const obj2 = {};
      for(const key in obj) {
        obj2[key] = resolveNestedPromises(obj[key]);
      }
      return promiseProps(obj2);
    }
    return obj;
  })

let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'url'));
let object = {
registration: [promise, promise, promise],
 contract: [promise, promise, promise],
 businessLicense: [promise, promise, promise],
 businessPlan: [promise, promise, promise]
};

promiseProps(object).then(console.log) // or 
resolveNestedPromises(object).then(console.log)
```